# .NET Identity Add userid from aspnetusers to custom table without controller

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have an interface which inherits from a model and that model currently has a relationship with the Aspnetusers table.

What I am trying to figure out is how to insert the userId from Aspnetuser table into my new table without going through a controller.

Example:

```
public async Task<WorkOutItems> CreateTodo(WorkOutItems WorkOutItem)
{
    var WorkOutItem = new WorkOutItems();
    invoice.ItemName = "Computer";
    invoice.CountOfItemName = 500;
    invoice.ClientId = _userManager; // what do i do here?
    _context.WorkOutItems.Add(WorkOutItem);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return WorkOutItem;
}


public class WorkOutItems
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    public int CountOfItemName { get; set; }

    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser Client { get; set; }

}



interface IWorkoutServices
{
    Task<List<WorkOutItems>> getTodoList();
    Task<WorkOutItems> GetToDoListById(int id);
    Task<WorkOutItems> CreateTodo(WorkOutItems TodoItems);
    Task UpdatePlayer(WorkOutItems TodoItems);
    Task DeletePlayer(WorkOutItems TodoItems);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are Using Identity then

```
 invoice.ClientId =User.Identity.GetUserId()
```

don't forget to import `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;`

EDIT++
try installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity in Nuget

Comment: I have tried importing the library to use User.Identity.GetUserId(); and it doesn't let me - is it maybe because i'm already using
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

Comment: try installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity in Nuget

Comment: Already installed the package in Nuget, i think i found another way around this via 
ClientId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value